# How to determine if node w lies on the path between node u and node v in a tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, lowest-common-ancestor

I am trying to solve a problem that requires me to determine if a node w lies on the path between node u and node v in a tree (not necessarily binary).

For example, for the following tree:

```
    1
  2   3
4  5 6  7
```

Node 2 lies on the path from node 4 to 7.

An obvious solution would be to obtain the euler tour of the tree and traverse the nodes that were visited between the first occurences of both nodes. However, that would be an O(n) solution in the worst case where n is the number of nodes in the tree. I read somewhere that this can be done using LCA (Lowest Common Ancestor). However, I can't seem to understand how. Could someone please advise me?

Comment: you want an advice for learning LCA or solve the problem? Say if you has a black box O(h)  algorithm for finding LCA, do you know how to use LCA to solve it?

Comment: I know how to find LCA of 2 nodes in tree using sparse table and RMQ. I want to solve problem described in the post. I just read that the problem can be solved efficiently using LCA. Maybe it could be solved using other methods too. But I cannot understand how LCA or any other methods could solve this problem.

Comment: I think if the following two conditions fulfills that the answer is yes?
let x = lca(u,v)
1. lca(w,u) = w or lca(w,v) = w
2. lca(w,x) = x

Comment: Do you have an explanation why this holds true?

Comment: if w has to lie on the path uv, then it must be under the subtree rooted at lca(u,v) and it is either u or v's ancestor?

Comment: What is the complexity of finding LCA?

Comment: @Anton.P The complexity of my LCA algorithm is O(1) after O(nlogn) preprocessing.

Comment: @shole Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Say A = LCA(u,v). The path between u and v is the path from u to A and from A to v. Check each of these nodes (going up from u and then up from v). If w is among them then it's on the path, otherwise it isn't.

Comment: This works, but it's also O(n) time in the worst case (if vertices with 1 child are allowed; it's O(log n) if every vertex has at least 2 children, since then the depth is also upper-bounded by O(log n).)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Do you think it's possible to do better than linear wrt the length of the path from u to v?

Comment: shole's comments on the question describe a way to do this in O(1).  (I actually wrote a "hint" answer describing the same thing, before realising the info was already there...)

Comment: You only get O(1) after preprocessing. This is O(h) with no preprocessing.

Comment: Fair enough.  I took the OP's question to be about using LCA preprocessing once to answer each query faster ("I read somewhere that this can be done using LCA (Lowest Common Ancestor)"), but that's admittedly not explicit in the question.  If every vertex has at least 2 children, then your O(h) is indeed better than O(n).  I think you still need to explain the (straightforward) technique to actually find A in O(h) time (to avoid giving a false positive to a query w that is an ancestor of A).